# User posting possible spam

Tags: discussion, spam

I have noticed the user [James Harvey](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/16618/james-harvey) appears to be going through all old migration questions and posting single link answers to extensions.

Comment: Yep - not on.  Just been through and downvoted all his answer - imo his account should be deleted as he is clearly just going through advertising an extension he has some kind of affiliation to.  Don't have a problem with links to extensions if it's part of a full answer, 1 liners, no thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the report. The user is destroyed.